# How can I sensibly strip all trailing hashtags out of an Instagram caption?

Tags: php, regex, instagram, text-processing

Many Instagram posts end with a plethora of hashtags, for example:

```
"This is one of the amazing Mountains you can find in the National Forest Park in #Zhangjiajie #Chinawhich is where James Cameron drew his inspiration for the flying mountains in #Avatar..

Credit: @phototravelnomads 
#pictoura #gydr 
#destinationearth #earthpix #ourlonelyplanet#wonderful_earthLife #timeoutsociety#fantastic_earthpics #liveoutdoors #igglobalclub#awesomeearth #mist_vision #earthdeluxe
# #worldbestgram #mthrworld #fantastic_earth#famouscaptures #destination_wow #dreamlifepix#wonderful_places #igworldclub #ig_global_life
#natureaddict #beautifuldestinations #traveler #guider#locals"
```

I'm looking to process the captions to remove the hashtag collection at the end, while leaving the rest intact. What would be a good approach to doing this? I'm sure I can figure out a brute force way, but I'm hoping to get some thoughts on an elegant solution. Doesn't have to be actual code. :)

Edit per burna's comment: The expected result would be:

```
"This is one of the amazing Mountains you can find in the National Forest Park in #Zhangjiajie #Chinawhich is where James Cameron drew his inspiration for the flying mountains in #Avatar..

Credit: @phototravelnomads"
```

Edit per Alan Moore's answer: This works quite well, but not in every situation. For instance, if the input text would be:

```
"This is one of the amazing Mountains you can find in the National Forest Park in #Zhangjiajie #Chinawhich is where James Cameron drew his inspiration for the flying mountains in #Avatar"
```

... it would be cut off from "#Zhangjiajie" on.

I'm thinking there's probably a bit more logic required, perhaps splitting the string into an array; checking if it ends in hashtags; if so then how many; if more than X (4?), cut it off from the first one in the last complete series.

Comment: Could you add the expected result after processing?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your question got mangled by the automatic formatting; you can check the edit history to see what I did to fix it (and while you're at it, check the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see what else is available).  You should always *preview* your posts here as well as proofreading them. ;)

Comment: @burna I've edited the question, but I think Alan Moore already answered it :)

Comment: @WalterVos Great, then appreciate his effort by accepting the answer :)

Comment: @burna After reviewing Alan's answer a bit furtherI see that it's not quite there yet.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this will do it:

```
$result = preg_replace('/#[#\w\s]*\z/', '', $subject);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rN2qZ6/1)

The regex matches a hash (`#`), followed by zero or more of the characters that make up hashtags plus the whitespace that separates them (`[#\w\s]*`), followed by the end of the string (`\z`).

`\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.  If there are other characters that are allowed in hashtags, or if digits are not allowed, let me know and I'll update the regex.

---

UPDATE:  If you want to remove all robo-tags while leaving the legitimate ones, there's probably no reliable way--certainly not with regexes alone.  However, this will remove all but the first *line* of hashtags:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^(#[#\w\h]+\R)#[#\w\s]*\z/m', '$1', $subject);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rN2qZ6/2)

`\h` matches only horizontal whitespace (space, tab, nbsp...), and `\R` matches any line separator (`\r\n` or any single vertical whitespace character).

As for hashtag-like things in the text, this won't touch them because it's anchored to the end of the text.  The beginning-of-line anchor (`^` in multiline mode) isn't really necessary, but it may help future readers of the regex (including yourself) understand what it does.  Of course, comments will help even more. ;)

Comment: Hi Alan, this works quite well, but it's a bit crude still. If the text does not contain a "large array of hashtags", but does end with one or two hashtags, they also get stripped. The problem is that people also use hashtags as words (ugh, people). For instance, if the input would be: "This is one of the amazing Mountains you can find in the National Forest Park in #Zhangjiajie #Chinawhich is where James Cameron drew his inspiration for the flying mountains in #Avatar"

Comment: To add: Regex may not be the way to go perhaps?

Comment: Regex is definitely not the *best* solution; it never is.  But I think it's good enough for this job.  Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the following should work:

```
$hashTag="pictoura #gydr 

destinationearth #earthpix #ourlonelyplanet#wonderful_earthLife #timeoutsociety#fantastic_earthpics #liveoutdoors #igglobalclub#awesomeearth #mist_vision #earthdeluxe

 #worldbestgram #mthrworld #fantastic_earth#famouscaptures #destination_wow #dreamlifepix#wonderful_places #igworldclub #ig_global_life

natureaddict #beautifuldestinations #traveler #guider#locals";

echo preg_replace('/(#.*\s*)/','',$hashTag);
```

That outputs:

`pictoura destinationearth natureaddict`

Good luck!!

Comment: Thanks angelcool.net but that just cuts it off from the first hashtag on (and then stops at newlines). See: https://regex101.com/r/jF1cI5/1